# addprefix command not recognized in makefile using nmake.exe windows

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make, nmake

```
all: prd.exe

CC=cl
CFLAGS=-O2 -I../src -I. /W4
LDFLAGS = /Zi
LIBSRC = $(addprefix ../lib/, \
        open.c malloc.c \
     ) \
     $(addprefix ../src/, \
        main.c \
      ) \
      helper.c

LIBOBJS = $(LIBSRC:.c=.o)

prd.exe: ../src/main.obj
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -Fe$@ *.o

../src/main.obj: ../src/main.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBOBJS) -c $< -Fo $@ 

.c.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBOBJS) -c $< -Fo $@ 

.c.i:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBOBJS) -C -E $< > $@

clean:
del /s /f /q ..\lib\*.o ..\src\*.o *.o *.exe *.pdb

distclean: clean
```

I get this error

fatal error U1000: syntax error : ')' missing in macro invocation at line 6

Am i missing something here? nmake does recognize addprefix, right?

Answer (score 3):

No, `addprefix` is a GNU make extension. You have a GNUmakefile that requires GNU make (gmake) to process.

Alternatively, you could rewrite the GNU makefile to not use GNU extensions. In your case this should be easy:

```
LIBSRC = $(addprefix ../lib/, \
        open.c malloc.c \
     ) \
     $(addprefix ../src/, \
        main.c \
      ) \
      helper.c
```

becomes

```
LIBSRC = ../lib/open.c ../lib/malloc.c ../src/main.c helper.c
```

Comment: Oh..my bad..so what is the equivalent for `addprefix` in nmake

Comment: Previously, I was doing the same thing. But now my code base is increasing and I somehow want to avoid pre-pending `../lib` to each and every file

Comment: I'm not an nmake buff, but I'm afraid there is no equivalent. See the nmake reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx

Comment: FWIW I regularly use cygwin's make with VisualStudio compilers. Works well, you can have properly portable makefiles (MacOS, Linux, Windows), and you don't have to deal with the mind bogglingly awful nmake.

Comment: @bobbogo that is probably the best "generic" nmake answer I have found so far!... I figured if I have to build things for visual studio targets I need to use nmake, so I started learning that (egghhh...) - but as you say... why not just use make! - note you can install something like mingw and use its make (if you don't want to install Cygwin)

Comment: @code_fodder I'm a big fan of _cygwin_ make, however I strive to never use _mingw_ make. I once got to a place where 5 backslashes  was too few, but six was too many. I think this was due to some brokenness introduced into _mingw make_ to handle Windows directory separators.

Comment: @bobbogo ah, interesting - I did notice some slight quirks between the two (I was trying to make sure that both work on the same makefile), but nothing too bad to put me off yet... for windows box I just didn't want to force people to depend on any specific version of make (i.e. try to keep it portable as poss). Also just realised I did not upvote you...+1 sir